# How to script or copy event notification objects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, events, database-administration

I need to transfer some server event [notifications objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453.aspx) from one SQL2K8 instance to another.

I wanted to use [sys.server_event_notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174982.aspx) view but the [event](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452.aspx) (e.g. DDL_TABLE_EVENTS, DDL_INDEX_EVENTS etc.) needed for the creation is not there.

I could not also find them in SSMS.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot

Comment: From a quick browse, I'd guess you use `sys.events` which seems to have an objectid (matching `sys.server_event_notifications`?) and a type (to `sys.event_notification_event_types`). But I'm unable to confirm this at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks

You pointed me to the right direction, what I needed was

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- distinct because I don't need all the child events
    a.*
  , c.type_name
FROM
    sys.server_event_notifications a
INNER JOIN sys.server_events b
ON  a.object_id = b.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.event_notification_event_types c
ON  b.event_group_type = c.type
```

Joining only to `sys.server_events` gives me all the child events, then I have to join again to `sys.event_notification_event_types` to get the event group name that I used for initial creation.